# I want to display the contents of id="first" when mouse over the id="visible"

Tags: html, css, hover

```
<div id="visible" style="float:left;">
    <img src="image1.jpg"  id="boom">            
</div>

<div id="first" style="float:left; ">
    <span class="bob">Flatkit</span>        
</div>
```

I tried the following code,but it didn't helped me.

```
#visible #first:hover ~ #visible>#first
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#visible :hover >#first
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#visible :hover + #first
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

It would be great if anyone can help me. I know it can be done using JavaScript but I want to execute this using CSS3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#visible, #first{ float: left;}            /* use stylesheets! not inline styles */

                 #first{ display:none;  }  /* hidden initially...                */
#visible:hover + #first{ display:block; }  /* show on #visible hover             */
```

```html
<div id="visible">  HOVER ME!</div>
<div id="first"><span class="bob">Flatkit</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#visible, #first{ float: left;} /* use stylesheets! not inline styles */

#first{display:none;}
#visible:hover + #first{ display:block; }
.one{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.two{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="visible" class="one"> Visible </div>
<div id="first" class="two"><span class="bob">Next Div</span></div>
```

Comment: Copying an answer just to add some `.one` and `.two` styles seems funny at least.

Comment: Every Question Is Not Same Two users Thinkings So Its Not Copying

Comment: Your answer adds no more value to the already answered ones. When you'll have more reputation, you'll be welcome to improve already existing answers by editing. I mean, imagine now a user that copies your answer just to add background color.... silly.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
 #first
 {
  display:none;
 }
 #visible:hover ~ #first
 {
  display:inline-block;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="visible" style="float:left;">
    Hello           
</div>
<div id="first" style="float:left;">
    <span class="bob">Flatkit</span>        
</div>

</body>
</html>
```